# Time Tracking Graph is not displayed in Issue View

Tags: project-management, jira, time-tracking

When I open an issue, I don't see time tracking section (mentioned here. We are using JIRA (v4.3.4). Are there some settings which needs to be turned on for this?

I have the 'Original Estimate' field in the Create/Edit issue screen; what I want to see is the Time traking section when I view an issue -

[image]

as seen in this page - http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/What+is+an+Issue

Note: I am talking about the issues assigned to me on which I have all the permissions(Edit etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure that time tracking is turned on and that the users have the proper permission to log time on issues.

go to administration>global settings>time tracking